# BlueJ For-each Loops

Tags: bluej

```
for(Pixel[] rowArray ; pixels) 
  { 
   for(Pixel pixObj: rowArray) 
   { 

   } 
}
```

For a pixel array having 36 rows and 22 columns, how many times will the code be executed?

Comment: Zero. Won't even compile.

Comment: If you wrote the semicolon intentionally, then it's a compile error. Otherwise, how many items will _what_ code be executed? The entire thing that you've posted will be executed only once as it is a normal block. If you mean the outer block, that would be 36. If you mean the innermost block, then 36x22.